# NHibernate QueryOver with an Or subquery

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Ok I'm losing on this one. I have an NHibernate query that looks something like this

```
  var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Lead>()
            .Where(x => x.Client == user.Client)
            .And(x => x.LeadType == leadType && x.LeadType != LeadTypeEnum.Self)
            .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Id()));
```

I use this

```
  var query = Session.QueryOver<Lead>()
            .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(subQuery);
```

This produces what I need

```
Where lead.id in (select Id from .......)
```

However, I need to add another subquery. Easy to do like above, but I need this to produce the following

```
Where lead.id in (select id from .....)
or lead.id in (select id from .......)
```

The problem is I'm always getting the following

```
Where lead.id in (select id from .....)
and lead.id in (select id from .......)
```

Could someone point me in the correct direction to get the **Or** please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an NH newbie myself , but you might want to try created a disjunction and adding the conditions to it, then adding the disjunction to the QueryOver `Where` call.

```
var disjunction = new Disjunction();
disjunction.Add(subQuery1);
disjunction.Add(subQuery2);
var query = Session.QueryOver<Lead>()
    .Where(disjunction);
```

Comment: I thought about something similar however, I get


Error 13 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver<wow.Common.Model.ContactLead,wow.Common.Model.ContactLead>' to 'NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion'

Comment: Have you tried something like `disjunction.Add(subQuery1.UnderlyingCriteria)` or `disjunction.Add(subQuery1.DetachedCriteria)`?

Comment: Not at my computer now, but if memory serves me I get the same or similar issue